# Как fwrite() занести данные в файл на указанное место, а не в конец файла?

Tags: php

```
$fp = fopen("log.log", "a+t"); // Открываем файл в режиме записи
$str=$email.' , '.$pass.' , '.$ip.' , '.$ip2.' , '.$browser.' , '.$referer.' , '.$host.' , '.$port.' , '.$connect.' , '.$time ."\n" ;
$test = fwrite($fp, $str); // Запись в файл
if ($test) echo 'Данные в файл успешно занесены.';
else echo 'Ошибка при записи в файл.';
fclose($fp); //Закрытие файла
```

Comment: Вообще-то fseek, но твои мечты про "указанное место" разобьются о суровую действительность, так что лучше ты это место руками не трогай, а пиши в конец, как послушный пионэр

Comment: Почитайте как открывать файл http://php.net/manual/ru/function.fopen.php и там же везде упоминается fseek. Только у вас длина записи переменная. Вы случайно затрете что нибудь не то, затрется ведь ровно столько же байт, сколько вы запишите. Так что писать можно блок только точно такой же длины как был до этого

Comment: М-да, представляю как в "указанном месте" добавляются кластеры диска для сохранения данных... Если так уж нужно "указанное место" - считывайте файл в буфер (переменную), меняйте ее строковыми функциями и снова сохраняйте. Но это напрочь неоптимально...